# Will a VB6 Application run on Windows 10

Tags: windows, vb6, compatibility

We have an legacy application(VB,.NET 2.0, Vs2005 COM dlls)  that runs fine on window 7, now what kind of issue can we forsee if we were to move to windows 10, 
i was reading this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/hh749939)

and in that it is mentioned that "Your app must not take a dependency on the VB6 runtime" but again in this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nb-no/vbrun/ms788708%28en-us%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) it is mentioned that it supports

my question is, am i looking into the correct document or can anyone share the correct link

Comment: Your VB.NET app uses the VB6 runtime?

Comment: Hmm, surely you are not going to submit your app for certification.  VB6 compatibility is a moving target, not every ActiveX control has a happy story.  You cannot get a warranty, testing is required.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first link only applies to apps that require *certification* - it does not relate to what is actually supported, only what is recommended.

The second link clearly states the VB6 runtime is supported in Windows 10.

> VB6 runtime will ship and will be supported in Windows 10 for the lifetime of the OS

Comment: what kind of apps require certification ? i know all drivers need the certification..i am planning to run it on windows-10 test it thoroughly..any problem you see with this approach

Comment: Store apps for example; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/hh968450.aspx - Why is your .Net project using the VB6 runtime anyway?

Comment: i just wanted to know if the current application that runs on window-7 would run smoothly on windows-10 as well, This is a Desktop application and not a store app.

Comment: There is no reason to expect problems on Win10 if your desktop app works fine on Win7, but it would be a good idea to test it.

Answer (score 3):

From [Getting Ready for Windows 10](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/06/22/getting-ready-for-windows-10-sdks-compatibility-bridges/) Windows blog post:

> Windows is committed to compatibility. The Windows compatibility team has been looking at user telemetry and reacting to feedback from Windows Insiders to ensure that existing apps work well with Windows 10. Windows 10 is designed to run Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1 software programs. And yes, everyone’s favorite VB6 Runtime will continue to work, too.

We have a .NET 4.0 application that references a vb6-written app via COM Interop and it runs just fine on Windows 10 with no special permissions or tweaking of User Account Control.

Comment: +1 we also have .Net applications that reference VB6 components via COM interop and they also work fine on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

I created a new VB6 exe on Windows 7, which uses the WebBrowser control.  Then copied only my new exe to a new Windows 10 trial I setup. (Did not copy any DLLs, etc..  my exe only).

Ran my VB6 program/exe on Windows 10, and it worked! It loaded a web page using the (I guess) latest Windows 10 WebBrowser control.

So at least I know I can develop VB6 WebBrowser stuff on Windows 7, and my exe works on Windows 10...

Please verify, thanks.  :-)